# How to list data from related tables in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

So my problem is with listing all data from related tables. I have two tables: Category with Id,Name and Entry with Title,Name,Username,Password,CategoryId. So i want the output to be All Entries listed but with Category.Name at the end.

Ex.

```
ID   Title      Name    Username     Password    Category
-------------------------------------------------------------

 1   Facebook   Peter    Batman      123456        Social Network
```

So any help, and hints how to do it.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Give us some code/structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use as below

```
var query = from cat in Category 
           join en in entry on cat.Id equals in.CategoryId
           select new{
             id=cat.Id,
             Title = en.Title,
             Name=en.Name,
             Username =en.Username,
             Password =en.Password.
             Category=cat.Category
           }
```

OR use as in your model property

```
 var query = from cat in Category 
           join en in entry on cat.Id equals in.CategoryId
           select new ModelName
           {
             id=cat.Id,
             Title = en.Title,
             Name=en.Name,
             Username =en.Username,
             Password =en.Password.
             Category=cat.Category
           }
```